# split pandas df row on delimiter and then rename another row based on index

Tags: python, pandas

lets say i have the following df:

```
 name    job    age&dob
 bob     teacher  35/1-1-85
 kyle    doctor   25/1-1-95
```

I want to split the rows age&dob based on the '/' delimiter which can be achieved by putting age&dob into a list and then stacking it. However, i do not know how to rename the row based on age&dob index. For example, i want this.

```
 name    metadata    age&dob   job
 bob     age         35        teacher
 bob     dob         1-1-85    teacher
 kyle    age         25        doctor
 kyle    dob         1-1-95    doctor
```

i want metadata to be created by the index based on the split. So in this case, since i know that age&dob.spilt('/')[0] is always going to be age, i want 35 to be there and then metadata to be updated to show age. I know how to split the df, its just the renaming of the additional row value.

Comment: Check out https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

Let us do

```
df['metadata'] = 'age&dob'
df['age&dob'] = df['age&dob'].str.split('/')
s=df.explode('age&dob').assign(metadata=df['metadata'].str.split('&').explode().tolist())
   name      job age&dob metadata
0   bob  teacher      35      age
0   bob  teacher  1-1-85      dob
1  kyle   doctor      25      age
1  kyle   doctor  1-1-95      dob
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, lets use `str.split`, `rename`, `stack` and finally `concat`

```
s = df['age&dob'].str.split('/',expand=True).rename({0 : 'age', 1 : 'dob'},axis=1)\
            .stack().reset_index(1)\
            .rename({'level_1' : 'metadata', 0 : 'age&dob'},axis=1)

df2 = pd.concat([df.drop(['age&dob'],axis=1),s],axis=1)

   name      job metadata age&dob
0   bob  teacher      age      35
0   bob  teacher      dob  1-1-85
1  kyle   doctor      age      25
1  kyle   doctor      dob  1-1-95
```

Comment: hey, this was working at some point but then i got a ValueError: Shape of passed values is (38, 7), indices imply (19, 7). im assuming this is because my indices are not unique? but tried to drop indices dupes. any clues?